# How to loop through the result of find in bash and perform operations on each of them

Tags: bash

I am very new to bash scripting. I need to perform same operation on 300 files. I have tried the following so far:

```
empty_files=$(find ./ -type f -empty)
echo "$empty_files"
```

Now I have the full path to all the 300 files, stored in variable empty_files.

Now what I want to do is, for each file in the result

1. go to it's parent's parent directory,
2. then go to the other child (sibling of earlier file's parent directory) and find a file by name 'abc.js' inside it
3. Now, inside abc.js, find a particular word (object property) "user"
4. now on the new line, insert a line of js code. (exact same code for all files)

Please let me know if it's possible from mac command line.
Thanks

Comment: So, you want to find all files named `abc.js` and insert a line?  First write a script that inserts a line into the file named in its first argument, then executed `find . -name abc.js -exec ./my_script {} \;`

Comment: The first line won't work if any of the pathnames contain whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
for file in "${empty_files[@]}"
do
    ... code that uses "$file"
done
```

You could also pipe directly from `find` into the loop:

```
find . -type f -empty | while read -r file
do
    ... code that uses "$file"
done
```

This version should work for any filenames that don't contain newline.